# How do I make a mob grinder in MCPE that actually spawns mobs

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Although I cannot show you an image I can describe. I basically killing the mobs by using fall damage, I make them falling into water more probable by having trap doors opened. I also have slabs to prevent spider spawning, but I don't know why any mobs are spawning. I am playing in am MCPE Realm that doesn't spawn mobs in the dark room. I also put torches around the dark room on the outside to increase the chance of mobs spawning inside. I built one above land and below land. I am not in a mycelium biome and I am not playing in peaceful. Flat world or regular it doesn't work. What is the problem.

Comment: You’re using mods which always creates additional complexity and confusion. Try creating one in a vanilla world. If that works, it’s a mod problem. If not, then try creating one in a custom void (still vanilla) world, so there are no competing mob spawns. If that works, then you know the problem: competing mob spawns. Combine that with the fact that in your mod, you can’t even prevent competitive spawning by lighting up areas, and you’ll see the problem. Grinders work only to the degree that move can’t spawn elsewhere. If this is the problem, you’re going to have to do a ton of slabbing.

Comment: No, I am not using mods, and I did create one in a vanilla world, and yes, I did do a lot of slabbing.

Answer (score 1):

The slabs are the problem. Remove them and it will work if the room is 100% dark and you are near the spawner.